# How do I launch an AWS EC2 instance using an AWS launch template with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to build an AWS EC2 redhat instance using an AWS launch template with Terraform.

I can create an launch template with a call to Terraform's resource `aws_launch_template`. My question is how do I use Terraform to build an EC2 server with the created launch template?

What Terraform aws provider resource do I call?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you specifically wanting to create a single EC2 instance or did you want to create an autoscaling group with a single EC2 instance in it as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53750292/2291321?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You can create an `aws_autoscaling_group` resource to make use of your new Launch Template. [Please see the example here for more details.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#with-latest-version-of-launch-template)

Code:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "foobar" {
  name_prefix   = "foobar"
  image_id      = "ami-1a2b3c"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
  availability_zones = ["us-east-1a"]
  desired_capacity   = 1
  max_size           = 1
  min_size           = 1

  launch_template = {
    id      = "${aws_launch_template.foobar.id}"
    version = "$$Latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for how to use the launch template.  Will give it a try, and report the results!

Comment: Thank you!  Was able to launch an image with the aws_autoscaling_group.  Had to changed the image_id  to ami-0080e4c5bc078760e, and ran perfectly!

Comment: What does the `$$Latest` version do?

Comment: You can use `$Latest`, `$Default`, or a version number to specify which launch template to use in your ASG. See here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#version - the extra `$` is prepended to escape Terraform's interpolation.

Comment: Still would be nice to launch a non-dynamically allocated EC2 instance via a launch template from Terraform.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I used to build an EC2 image with a launch template.

```
variable "aws_access_key" {}
variable "aws_secret_key" {}

provider "aws" {
    access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
    secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
    region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "foobar" {
    name_prefix   = "foobar"
    image_id      = "ami-0080e4c5bc078760e"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
    availability_zones = ["us-east-1a"]
    desired_capacity   = 1
    max_size           = 1
    min_size           = 1

    launch_template = {
      id      = "${aws_launch_template.foobar.id}"
      version = "$$Latest"
    }
}
```

Many thanks Adil!

Answer (score 1):

There is not = sign in launch_template block

```
launch_template {
    id      = "${aws_launch_template.foobar.id}"
    version = "$$Latest"
  }
```